# Lucene LaLong query and Query string in Geode

Tags: java, lucene, geode

In Geode version 1.10.0, how can I create a LuceneQuery from LuceneQueryFactory that executes both

1. Lucene query string
2. Dynamic query

in one go?

In other words, is there a mechanism to combine the below queries and execute them as one single query?

```java
LuceneQuery<Long, Customer> luceneQuery1 =
        luceneService
            .createLuceneQueryFactory()
            .setLimit(100)
            .create("customerIndex", "customerReg", "postcode:abc def", "customerId");
```

and

```java
LuceneQuery<Long, Customer> luceneQuery2 =
        luceneService
            .createLuceneQueryFactory()
            .setLimit(100)
            .create("customerIndex", "customerReg", index -> IntPoint.newRangeQuery("age", 20, 30));
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else hitting the same problem, the answer can be found in the [Apache Geode Users mailing list](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.apache.geode.user%20order%3Adate-backward), specifically on [this thread](https://markmail.org/message/ijah7tjmpoazo6pf).